# I need to return XML data formatted data from a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostreSQL 14.3.
I am trying to put something similar to this as a PostgreSQL Function:

```
select xmlelement(name car, xmlforest(make, model))
from cars
```

and run it against a table like this:

```
table cars   make varchar(20)   model varchar(20)
    
data ('Dodge','Viper'), ('Ford','Thunderbird')
```

I am missing a root element and I cannot seem to add one.

I would like to see:

```
<cars>  
    <car><make>Dodge</make><model>Viper</model></car>  
    <car><make>Ford</make><model>Thunderbird</model></car>
</cars>
```

but what I get is:

```
<car><make>Dodge</make><model>Viper</model></car>
<car><make>Ford</make><model>Thunderbird</model></car>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works, using XMLAGG to aggregate all rows into a single document:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name cars, XMLAGG(x)) 
FROM (
    SELECT xmlelement(name car, xmlforest(make, model)) 
    FROM cars
) sub(x);
```